# How to generate setters and getters, and define Q_PROPERTY() with the C++ preprocessor

Tags: c++, qt4, c-preprocessor

I'm designing a QT4 class. So far my class looks like this:

```
class GIHNode : public QObject, public QGraphicsItem
{

Q_OBJECT
Q_INTERFACES( QGraphicsItem )
[...]
public:
void setInteger(int);
int getInteger();

[..]
private:
int Integer; Q_PROPERTY(int Integer READ getInteger WRITE setInteger)
// Definition I'd like to replace

The setters and getters are implemented like this:
void GIHNode::setInteger(int x){Integer=x;}
int GIHNode::getInteger(){return Integer;}
```

I'd like to define a macro that does all this work for me.
I have tried this for the definition of a variable and the text inside `Q_PROPERTY`:

```
#define ID(x) x
#define STR_HELPER(x,y) ID(x)y
#define STRGET(x) STR_HELPER(get,x)
#define STRSET(x) STR_HELPER(set,x)
#define EXPORTEDVAR(type,varname) type varname; Q_PROPERTY(type varname READ STRGET(varname) WRITE STRSET(varname))
```

When I replace the line:

```
int Integer; Q_PROPERTY(int Integer READ getInteger WRITE setInteger)
```

with

```
EXPORTEDVAR(int,Integer)
```

the macro is correctly pre-processed, and it's replaced with:

```
int Integer; Q_PROPERTY(int Integer READ getInteger WRITE setInteger)
```

I have checked manually with cpp. The code compiles, but I can't get the property of an instance of this class. 
I'm using the metaobject (from QT4 moc) of an instance of this class to retrieve the properties, but I can't find it.
I suppose this has something to do with the pre-processor, but I don't know how to investigate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moc doesn't expand macros with arguments (See [moc Limitations](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html#limitations)), so it doesn't see your `Q_PROPERTY` statements.